# style losing through Apache proxy

Tags: apache, xhtml, styles, mod-proxy-html

I have an Apache httpd 2.4 with html_proxy_module enabled.

It's configured to receive several different context-root in this way:

```
www.xxxxx.com/rorac/
www.xxxxx.com/saas01/
```

And these different requests are redirected to their own Tomcats, some are Tomcat 7 and others are Tomcat 6.

I've found that my applications use different context-roots and different paths to get the .css, .xhtml, .jpg and all them are covered in the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse in the httpd.conf, but I'm still losing some styles that are included in the .xhtml files.

Another thing that i've seen is that the source code is losing the header definition:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Has anybody found a problem like this? I don't know if the problem with the headers can influence the problem with the styles.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have no answers, but I do know that if a document is offered to the browser without a proper DOCTYPE declaration, it does have a drastic effect on how it's rendered, because it will be rendered in quirks mode. (Unless it is actual XHTML, served up with `application/xhtml+xml` for a file type and with a proper namespace, then many browsers don't need the DOCTYPE declaration and they will render in standards mode regardless.)

Comment: yes, I think it too, the problem is why does Apache make lose the DOCTYPE declaration? And what can I do to avoid it?